# Compute screen location based on initial coords and angle of movement

Tags: javascript, css-animations, trigonometry

Given initial coordinates (the `left` and `top` css properties) of an absolutely positioned element on screen, and an angle of movement, how can I find out the values I should feed to `transform: translate` to animate the element? (The element would eventually fall off-screen, so one of the final coords will be 0 or `window.innerWidth` or `window.innerHeight`.)

For example, starting from `left: 0` and `top: 0`, and given an angle of 90°, the destination point would be at `left` equal to `window.innerWidth` and `top` equal to 0. If the angle is 135°, the element would end up in the bottom right corner, etc. How can I calculate this for any angle?

(transform: translate takes deltas as parameters, not absolute positions; either is fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually fairly simple trig. Based on the example you have given:

1. Your known quantities are initial coords `{ x: 0, y: 0 }` and `{ angle: 90 /* in degrees*/ }`
2. Find x-distance between initial x-coord and `{ window.innerWidth if angle is between 90-270 or 0 if angle between 0-90 & 270-360 }`
3. Find the cosine of angle and multiply it with x-distance
4. Find y-distance between initial y-coord and { window.innerHeight if angle between 180-360 or 0 if angle between 0-180 }
5. Find the sine of angle and multiply it with y-distance
6. Add the initial x-coord with result of cosine * x-distance. This gives new x-coordinate
7. Add the initial y-coord with result of sine * y-distance. This gives new y-coordinate
8. Add some buffer to xnew and ynew so they fall off screen

For moving the element, you no longer require `transform`. You can simply add a `transition` CSS property and define new coords with new class added to that element. [`JSFiddle` Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hr7m5qbb/3/)

HTH